# Changing name/ip of Domain Controller/DNS/DHCP Server after migrating from 2012 to 2019

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, migration, windows-server-2019

We are prepping a migration of our AD server (DNS/DHCP/Print/Azure AD Connect) from 2012 to 2019. I can't find a definitive answer on changing a DC's ip/computer name post-migration.

Prep:

- spun up new server 2019 vm
- joined to existing 2012 domain controller, all computers/users appear to be syncing correctly both ways
- dns is syncing, forwarder on new server currently pointing old server's ip but I assume that changes once transfer FSMO roles
- exported printer data from old server and imported to new, all looks good

To complete the migration, steps:

1. Run Export-DhcpServer on the old server to get all the leases/config info for dhcp
2. Import that list to new server
3. Transfer the 5 FSMO roles to the new server
4. Uninstall AD on old server, then shutdown
5. Install new version of AD Connect for sycing to Azure

The issue is we have loads of devices on our network that utilize the computer name of our 2012 AD server as well as devices with static IP's set for DNS.

After completing migration steps above, we'd like to:

- change the new servers static ip to be the same as the old servers
- change the server/computer name (not actual domain name) of the new server (ie srv-dc02) to be the same as the old server (srv-dc01)

Is there any risk to making these changes?

Comment: Only thing I'd mention is that you have to explicitly remove the old server from AD after you shut it down, so the new server will allow the rename. I haven't tried changing name / static IP on a server so I can't provide an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Microsoft, renaming a domain controller is a bad idea and should be avoided. Microsoft compiled a list of many of the problems you may encounter below.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/rename-dc-to-preserve-old-name-and-ip-address/ba-p/850935

Generally, it isn't a good idea to change the name for a server that is performing too many functions and providing services to clients. It's also one reason that CNAMEs exist.

Comment: Ultimately, we're just going to change IP's and deal with any apps using the dns name. Not worth the additional risk.